# Blackberry no application instance

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I use the Eclipse Blackberry SDK, i created a Project LIBRARY, then i need pass values to a page (example: food.php) by POST, but when I try to create the instance of Criteria, the program return this message 'no application instance', i'm very confused because when I use the same code in BlackBerry Application don't happen that

REMEMBER THIS IS A PROJECT BLACKBERRY LIBRARY(NO APPLICATION)

This is my code

```
double lng = 0.0;
double lat = 0.0;
try{
    BlackBerryCriteria myCriteria = new BlackBerryCriteria();
    //myCriteria.enableGeolocationWithGPS(BlackBerryCriteria.FASTEST_FIX_PREFERRED);
    myCriteria.setMode(LocationInfo.GEOLOCATION_MODE);                          
    BlackBerryLocationProvider myProvider = (BlackBerryLocationProvider)LocationProvider.getInstance(myCriteria);(HERE IS THE PROBLEM)                      
    BlackBerryLocation myLocation;
    myLocation = (BlackBerryLocation) myProvider.getLocation(60);
    lat = myLocation.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLatitude();
    lng = myLocation.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLongitude();
    double alt = myLocation.getQualifiedCoordinates().getAltitude();
}
catch(Exception e){             
    System.out.println("ERRORRRR " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Why is this a Library?  When you make this a Library, what actually triggers the code to run?  Remember a Library is expected to be shared code, shared by a number of applications.

Comment: @paqogomez, please don't add tags unless you're sure they are appropriate.  This is not a C# question.